# Python way to detect if list of list of from-to values contains sequential numbers to the max

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of id as the key with a list of list that contains a from and to integer value for the given id.  So it would look something like this:

`{1: [[0,100], [100, 500], [500, 800]], 2: [[0, 700], [800, 1000]]}`

I am trying to set up a way to check to make sure that the sequences of numbers for each id provides continuous lists of numbers with no skips.  So in the example above, id 2 would get flagged because it goes from 700 to 800 rather than 700 to 700.  I am not sure what the best way to do this would be though.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you show the non-best way you've written, we can help fix the problems with it.

Comment: are the ids always 1,2,3,...n?

Comment: No the ids will be some integer up to 4 digits, but will be a unique id

Comment: Would `[[0, 700], [699, 1000]]` be valid?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
from itertools import chain
for key,value in a.iteritems():
    lst=list(chain(*sorted(value)))
    if len([i for i in lst if lst.count(i)==1])==2:
        print "okay with key %s"%key
    else:
        print "Flagged with key %s"%key
```

For you input:

```
{1: [[0,100], [100, 500], [500, 800]], 2: [[0, 700], [800, 1000]]}
```

Output will be:

```
okay with key 1
Flagged with key 2
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

using the pairwise recipe of itertool:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

data = {1: [[0,100], [100, 500], [500, 800]], 2: [[0, 700], [800, 1000]]}
for k,v in data.items():
    for a,b in pairwise(v):
        if a[-1]!=b[0]:
            print("key",k,"fail elemen",a,"and elemn",b,"in value",v)
```

ouput

```
key 2 fail elemen [0, 700] and elemn [800, 1000] in value [[0, 700], [800, 1000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a different solution.  See below:

```
d = {1: [[0,100], [100, 500], [500, 800]], 2: [[0, 700], [800, 1000]]}
for a in d.keys():
    x = [[i,i+1] for i,v in enumerate(d[a][:-1]) if v[1] != d[a][i+1][0]]
    if len(x) > 0:
        print a
```

So then 2 is printed.

Thank you all anyway for your suggestions.